# Executing two queries and exiting a unique table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database, and I would like to get data where the username is equal to `x` and I would also like to get data regardless of the user.

I have the two queries:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as month, COUNT(*) as count 
from DB_NAME 
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND userid = 'userid' 
GROUP BY month
```

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as month, COUNT(*) as count 
from DB_NAME 
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY month
```

Expected output:

```
+-------+------+-----+
| month | user | all |
+-------+------+-----+
|     1 |  100 | 200 |
|     2 |   90 | 150 |
+-------+------+-----+
```

Comment: What is the problem? You have 2 queries. Only the second query can produce the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some conditional aggregation is what you are after here:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(date) as month, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN userid = 'userid' THEN 1 END) as user,
  COUNT(*) as count 
from DB_NAME 
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY month;
```

Comment: You nailed it, thanks